# Replace spine for all shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending, blending-objects

Why can't I select the `replace spine` option? This option is non-action for me?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need another path.

Based upon your image, you merely have a blend selected. To replace the spine, first draw a new spine -- the path you want the blend to follow. Then select the new path, and the blend and `Replace Spine` should be available.